# Many To Many Relationship EF 6 (4 table and 1 many to many relationship) how to select with linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have 4 tables and between them there is one that is an intermediate table `AM_PERFIL_APLICACIONES_TBL` and when the mapping the intermediate table does not appreciate me in the edmx and I have read that several articles in which they explain that it is a matter of relations of many to many.

The question is how could I do a select to the 4 tables with Linq.

How can I `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE` the table `AM_PERFIL_APLICACIONES_TBL`.

I have something like this

```
var query_modulo = (from a in menu.AM_USUARIOS_TBL
                                    join b in menu.AM_PERFIL_APLICACIONES_TBL on a.ID_PERFIL equals b.ID_PERFIL
                                    join c in menu.AM_APLICACIONES_TBL on b.ID_APLICACION equals c.ID_APLICACION
                                    join d in menu.AM_MODULOS_TBL on c.ID_MODULO equals d.ID_MODULO
                                    where a.ID_USUARIO == _usrid
                                    select new { d.ID_MODULO, d.DESCRIPCION }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: If you set up your model properly, you do not need to update `AM_PERFIL_APLICACIONES_TBL`. EF will figure it out from your model and update that table for you.

Comment: Can you explain to me how can I do a proper set up to the model????

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: One more thing, I could do a select when I a setup?

Comment: What do you mean? I do not get your question.

Comment: If I setup my model I could do select with linq like I describe in the question??? sorry I'm new with entity

Comment: Please read that article. Yes you can.

Comment: I already did what you said but i dont know how to join the tables with linq

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44242627/3692034)

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your object model if it is a Many-to-Many table between Usuarios (U) and Aplicaniones (A) you would likely have a collection of (A) inside each (U), and a collection of (U) inside of each (A).

However, this is on the assumption that your linking table, Perfil_Aplicaniones (PA) is set up to just contain the ID of (U) (assumed to be ID_Perfil) and the ID of the Aplicanion. (A) (assumed to be ID_Aplicanion)

If this is the case, Entity Framework will handle the intermediary table automatically. To set up a new link between (U) and (A) you add the (A) reference to your u.Aplicaniones collection, and you add the (U) reference to your A.Usarios (or Perfils, whichever it is) When you persist the objects, EF should create the joining record automatically.

If instead though your (U) and (A) entities contain collections of PAs instead, then you will need to create the (PA) entity explicitly, set the references to the (U) and (A) records, then add that (PA) record to the U.Perfil_Aplicaniones and the A.Perfil_Aplicaniones respectively.

It all depends on how your entities (classes) are structured.  EF can manage linking tables automatically, but from memory the linking table must contain only the linking ID columns. Otherwise you have to map the linking table manually and manage the associations.